# Using locks doesn't prevent Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

This question has been asked many times, but this is a special case.

```
public class JobStatusMonitor
{
    private static List<Job> _runningJobs = new List<Job>();
    private static object myLock = new object();

    public static void AddJob(GPSJob input)
    {
        lock (myLock)
            _runningJobs.Add(input);
    }

    public static void Start(int pollInterval)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var removeJobs = new List<GPSJob>();
            lock (myLock)
            {
                foreach (var job in _runningJobs)
                {
                    if (job.IsComplete())
                    {
                        removeJobs.Add(job);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var job in removeJobs)
            {
                _runningJobs.Remove(job);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pollInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

The list _runningJobs is private, so nothing outside of this class can modify it unless it uses the AddJob method.  The AddJob method uses the same lock as the foreach loop so it shouldn't be able to modify the collection while it is iterating.

My understanding of what should be happening is Start(5000) gets called, there is nothing in the list so it skips to Thread.Sleep().  Background processes add jobs to the list. The while loop returns to the foreach loop and applies the lock.  While iterating over the list any other threads that attempt to add to the collection wait until iteration is complete.  As soon as iteration completes each of those threads will add their job, the lock will not cause race conditions even if there are many threads attempting to add jobs.

What actually happens is any job that is added while this thread is sleeping is added successfully.  Jobs that are added while this list is iterating do not wait for iteration to complete despite the lock.

Why doesn't the lock prevent this error?

EDIT: Copy to a new list within the lock eliminates the error.

```
public class JobStatusMonitor
{
    private static List<Job> _runningJobs = new List<Job>();
    private static object myLock = new object();

    public static void AddJob(GPSJob input)
    {
        lock (myLock)
        {
           _runningJobs.Add(input);
        }
    }

    public static void Start(int pollInterval)
    {
        while (true)
        {

            lock (myLock)
            {
                var completeJobs = _runningJobs.Where(job => job.IsComplete()).ToList();
                foreach (var job in completeJobs)
                {
                    _runningJobs.Remove(job);
                    job.TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
                }       
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pollInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your final `foreach` is modifying the collection outside of a lock.

Comment: How do you know that jobs are added during the iteration? Do you have evidence of this? And why is the Remove() outside of the lock?

Comment: It seems like you are using a list to simulate a queue.  Why not just use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) (which is _already_ thread-safe) in a `while` loop rather than trying to enumerate a list and blocking while other threads try to add items to it?

Comment: @DStanley He can remove jobs in the middle of the list if they completed before the others.

Comment: Do you call `Start` from different threads or do you just call it once?

Comment: Start is called in the once in the initialization using 
            Task.Run(() => { JobStatusMonitor.Start(pollInterval); });  There is no await because it runs permanently in the background for the life of the application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was spotted by @Philipe, you're modifiying the list outside of the lock. You should have all your modifying calls protected by the lock.

To simplify, you can just compute the new list of non completed job and swap with the current job list inside the lock. Something along the lines of:

```
lock(myLock) {
    var newRunningJobs = _runningJob.Where(j => !Job.IsComplete(j)).ToList();
    _runningJob = newRunningJobs;
}
```

Comment: Edited the question with the solution based on the reverse of this solution. I needed to do work on the completed jobs beyond removing them from the list but that isn't included in this example for simplicity.

Comment: That creates a new instance (reference) of the collection. Not sure that is desirable.

Comment: I suppose that is safe though, because it's a private member

Comment: That is why it works.  The public method updates the source list and and the iteration is performed on the new copy (that doesn't get updated until the next cycle) so the collection being iterated is not being modified during iteration.  The lock works on ToList but not on add + foreach for some unknown reason.

Comment: @fjardon  Similar kind of situation I'm facing, but I've used Property(of the list) instead of List itself, all modification and reading is done through this property and in both Set and Get portion of property I have put lock. and can you clear me what is difference between locking by `myLock` object and locking by that list itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `_runningJobs.Remove(job);` is not in a lock. The collection can't be aware of it, and you are removing items from it while potentially having a lock on it in `AddJob`. Move the removal of jobs in a lock or wrap it in one and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I moved everything into the lock except the thread.Sleep() and got the same error

Comment: @Adam What error did you get? Can you describe exactly what is not working as expected?

Comment: I do not think he should edit the question. He tested this answer and says it does not work. The answer appears fine to me and would like him to explain what is not working, but the original question stands.

Comment: The error did not change with the second loop moved into the lock.  It was the same error in the same place as described in the original question.